# Error Message (via Firefox) when using the Accessibility Checker Plugin in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, accessibility, ckeditor4.x

**[RESOLVED]**

I get this error message when I click on the Check Accessibility icon on the CKEditor toolbar: ***t(...).closest is not a function***. I see this message when I use the Firefox debugger.

The version of A11ychecker I am using was last updated, 30 Mar 2018.

This error occurs on line 3119 of `plugin.js`, which reads: ***expected: t(this).closest(".quail-test").data("expected")***.

I have tested this issue using the following versions of CKEditor: 4.5.10 and 4.9.2.

For me, the issue occurs every time the Check Accessibility button is clicked **AND** an accessibility issue exists. If no accessibility issues exist, Firefox does not display an error. It may be worth noting that the message box which is displayed always shows the message The document does not contain any accessibility issues, even when issues exist.

The code is running on Windows Server 2012 R2. The JQuery version being used is: v1.2.6.

This issue also occurs when using Internet Explorer.

Does anyone have any ideas on this one? I have also [posted on GitHub](https://github.com/cksource/ckeditor-plugin-a11ychecker/issues/255).

Comment: Could you try installing (which in this case is simply dropping editor folder to server) CKEditor as standalone application and checking if A11y checker will work out side of your application? If it will, this means there is some script in your application which conflicts with some A11y checker library. To check which one it is, you can remove them all, clear browser cache and start adding them one by one to see where error pops out.

Comment: Please also check which IE version (if it is not too old) you use and what level of security settings have you set as it may be too high and block scripts. Finally does the A11y demo works in your IE  https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/accessibilitychecker.html ?

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVED]

It transpired that a variable referenced in one of the many included JavaScript files, was undefined. This has apparently gone unnoticed for years. I only found it because I was updating JQuery using the jQuery Migrate plugin, and it wrote a message to the console telling me that a variable was undefined.

As soon as this was rectified, the Accessibility Checker sprang to life.

It certainly shows that j.swiderski was on the right track. Thanks for that.